# Prevent LaTeX from separating sections in multicolumn structure

Tags: multicolumn, columnbreak

How do I prevent LaTeX from separating sections in multicolumn structure? I want to have continuous text without any breaking. I want this behavior in all sections and pages.

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}



\ifthenelse{\lengthtest { \paperwidth = 11in}}
    { \geometry{top=.25in,left=.5in,right=.5in,bottom=.8in} }
    {\ifthenelse{ \lengthtest{ \paperwidth = 297mm}}
        {\geometry{top=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm} }
        {\geometry{top=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm} }
    }

\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}
\raggedright
\footnotesize
\begin{multicols}{3}

\section{\color{blue}{\textbf{///////////////////////////}}}

\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\     
\end{tabular}


\section{\color{blue}{\textbf{///////////////////////////}}}

\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\                     
\end{tabular}


\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**-----------------**

**New error:**
Based on mentioned @David Carlisle answer, the presented code for `longtable` version is only valid for one page. If we have more than one page (for example 3 page) it returns something like this. Generally we have different errors in higher page numbers.

page 2:

[image]

page 3:

[image]

Comment: a `tabular` is a box and will not break so the table will not move to where your arrow is, which would leave the section heading on its own at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I want some part of section in first column (as much as possible) and the rest of section in another column. In above example there is a empty space in end of first column. How can I have this behavior?

Comment: but the only thing that could go there is a section heading and latex doesn't break after a section heading so nothing fits in that space.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So we can't have continuous behavior in multicolumn without any separating (in above style)? Any tricky way to do this?

Comment: It is nothing to do with multicolumn: it is a feature of `tabular` imagine if that was an image of the same size , you presumably would not expect the image to split. To the page breaking routine there is no difference between an image, a tabular or a letter in a 5cm high font, they are just an unbreakable rectangle to be positioned.  You could use `supertab` or other multi-page table environments that do break.

Comment: Why are you using a tabular? I would always do things like this with a list.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Can You prepare an answer for it? thanks.

Answer (score 7):

It is not really related to `multicol`. `tabular` is an unbreakable box, and latex does not break after a section heading so the second section does not fit in the indicated space. If you use a breakable table structure such as `supertabular` then there is a possibility of the heading and start of table fitting.

---

**longtable version**

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{longtable}


\ifthenelse{\lengthtest { \paperwidth = 11in}}
    { \geometry{top=.25in,left=.5in,right=.5in,bottom=.8in} }
    {\ifthenelse{ \lengthtest{ \paperwidth = 297mm}}
        {\geometry{top=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm} }
        {\geometry{top=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm} }
    }

\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}
\raggedright
\footnotesize
\begin{multicols}{3}

\section{\color{blue}{\textbf{///////////////////////////}}}

\setbox0\vbox{\csname col@number\endcsname=1
\begin{longtable}{@{}ll@{}}
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\     
\end{longtable}\unskip\unpenalty\unpenalty\bigskip}
\unvbox0


\section{\color{blue}{\textbf{///////////////////////////}}}

\setbox0\vbox{\csname col@number\endcsname=1
\begin{longtable}{@{}ll@{}}
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\                     
\end{longtable}\unskip\unpenalty\unpenalty\bigskip}
\unvbox0


\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

---

**supertabular version**

However `supertabular` as used below appears to force a page not column break (probably fixable) and `longtable` by default doesn't work in multicolumn.

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{supertabular}


\ifthenelse{\lengthtest { \paperwidth = 11in}}
    { \geometry{top=.25in,left=.5in,right=.5in,bottom=.8in} }
    {\ifthenelse{ \lengthtest{ \paperwidth = 297mm}}
        {\geometry{top=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm} }
        {\geometry{top=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm} }
    }

\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}
\raggedright
\footnotesize
\begin{multicols}{3}

\section{\color{blue}{\textbf{///////////////////////////}}}

\begin{supertabular}{@{}ll@{}}
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
\verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\     
\end{supertabular}


\section{\color{blue}{\textbf{///////////////////////////}}}

\begin{supertabular}{@{}ll@{}}
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\ 
    \verb!----!    & --------------------------------------- \\                     
\end{supertabular}


\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think we should try to fix your mentioned problem.

Comment: @user2991243 I extended the answer with a (working) `longtable` version.

Comment: I found a problem. When I have more than two pages your code turns something like this PDF: http://www.mediafire.com/file/b5ycfxmsdkc2ec4/LaTeX_error_1.pdf Any solution?

Comment: I have mentioned problem in `longtable` version. Your code is only valid for one page not for more than one page.

Comment: @user2991243 no if there is a problem make a test file either edit your question or ask a new one

Comment: Thank you for comment. I add more information in question.

Comment: I liked David Carlisle solution. I tested it with an small paragraph between each section and its longtable environment. With the additional rubber space, the text is evenly distributed. **This is a good way to use longtable with multicolum**.